# Incomplete Seam Marking

Tags: uv

I'm pretty new and want to mark some seams, but it won't let me mark them on certain edges and I don't know why. See image for what I'm talking about. It is an incomplete mark seam.

Thanks, guys!
 [image: incomplete seam]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inspect your model for duplicate vertices and zero area polygons and vertices which are near each other yet do not share a face.  Duplicate vertices are sometimes created by extrusion operations .  You may move  vertices to see if  duplicates are in the same location.  Alt-Clicks should select vertex sequences which can be moved and thus inspected.  Look at the model in wireframe mode and check the vertex count which is displayed at the top in blender.

If you have little time investment in the model consider starting from scratch.  Sometimes for simple models this is faster.

Has a UV Unwrap failed?

Comment: Ah! It was overlapping vertices. I saw it when I moved one around on the wireframe.
And the unwrap looked awful with things zigzagging all over the place. Now it looks good after deleting extra vertices. Gotta watch my extrudes next time.
Thanks!